# OleDb возвращает ошибку для varchar C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, firebird, oledb

уже 4ый день сижу с проблемой при попытке получить колонку, через OleDb для firebird (lcpi.data.oledb), с типом varchar(Любого размера) выкидывает исключение:

```
[LCPI.IBProvider.5] Ошибка получения данных колонки [номер: 1][STREET]. Статус: DBSTATUS_E_CANTCONVERTVALUE.

Код ошибки COM: DB_E_CANTCONVERTVALUE.
--------------------------------
2. [lcpi.data.oledb.OleDbDataReader] Чтение значения колонки "STREET" OLE DB набора рядов завершилось с ошибками. Индекс колонки: 0. Порядковый номер колонки: 1.

Код ошибки COM: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED.
--------------------------------
3. [lcpi.data.oledb.OleDbDataReader] Ошибка чтения значения колонки "STREET". Порядковый номер колонки: 1. OLE DB тип привязки: BYREF_WSTR. Размер буфера для значения: 4. Статус значения: E_CANTCONVERTVALUE.

Код ошибки COM: E_FAIL.
INFO  2021-10-12 20:51:03,966 ExchangeService        Все задачи обмена завершены.
```

строка подключения:

```
Provider=LCPI.IBProvider.5;Password=password;User ID=USER;location=155.136.251.14/41035:D:\Base\BASE.FDB;dbclient_library=fbclient.dll
```

Код получения:

```
            string query = $@"
            SELECT Spr_street.ST_NAMESHOW Street FROM Spr_street ";

 OleDbCommand cmd = createCMD(connection, query);
            using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    HouseDBData Housedb = new HouseDBData()
                    {
                        Street =rdr[1].ToString(),
                    };
                    result.Add(Housedb);
                }
            }
```

Метод createCMD(connection, query);

```
   private OleDbCommand createCMD(FireBirdDBConnection connection, string query)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = connection.GetConnection();
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            return cmd;
        }
```

Важно отметить, что для других типов работает все корректно ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, я уже отчаялся

Comment: Какая строка исходного кода дает сбой?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky На  Street =rdr[1].ToString() кидает ошибку, причем если поставить другую колонку с типом int, то все выполняется отлично

Comment: Выбирается одно значение, а индекс указан [1]. С нуля же нумерация?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я лишние поля из запроса и класса убрал, чтоб не занимали место в вопросе, к тому же они выводятся(тип не varchar), а нумерацию забыл изменить на 0

Comment: **OLE DB тип привязки: BYREF_WSTR.** Похоже, что тип данных UNICODE.

Comment: [тыц](https://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=875384&msg=11220435)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky  СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov СПАСИБО!!